# Symfony 2 routing in controler

Tags: url, variables, symfony, routes

I have simple question. Is there any way to use routing in cotroler to get from link like this:

```
some-text-link-282237
```

value 282237.

By now i'm passing whole url by:

```
@Route("/route/{id}", name="my_route")
```

and then preg matching it, but maybe there is a cleaner way. The value is allways at the end of string separate by last (-)

Thanks for any help, and sorry for language errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/route/{slug}-{id}",
 *        name="route_name",
 *        requirements={"slug":"[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+","id":"\d+"})
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a route like this : `@Route("/route/{some}/{text}/{link}/{id}` and get directly your id as a parameter or change the separator route : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html to use directly "-" as a route separator

Comment: Thanks but i can't, i need it only in this case so i can't change route parameters for whole project. So i guess preg_match stays huh?

Comment: So why don't you call this uri : `some/text/link/282237` ? And use every parameters with this kind of route : `@Route("/route/{some}/{text}/{link}/{id}`

Comment: but if it's just for this case then you can use the link i gave you before. It's allows you to change the separators just for a function. And this way you can keep the slashes for all the other functions.

Comment: But the url have to look like http:// www .portal.com/category/subcategory/some-text-link-999999

Comment: ah okay he wants you to only change the separator for a part of the url O_o How do you generate this url? (php, twig ?) can you show us some code?